# There's no error or warning displayed but my code won't run, it says console application stopped working

Tags: c++

A basic application of inheritance on classes..Create a class Person which has derived classes Faculty and Student. Now derive class TA from classes Faculty and Student. Implement constructors and print function for each class.

```
 #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    class person {
    protected:
        string name;
    public:
        person() {};
        void setter(string x) {
            name = x;
        }
        virtual void print() {
            cout << "The name of faculty member is:" << name;
        }
    };
    class faculty : public person {
    public:
        virtual void print() {
            cout << "The name of faculty member is:" << name;
        }
    };
    class student : public person {
    public:
        virtual void print() {
            cout << "The name of student is:" << name;
        }

    };
    class TA : public faculty, public student {
    public:
        virtual void print(string y) {
            string nm = y;
            cout << "The name of TA is:" << nm;
        }
    };

    int main() {
        person *p= NULL; faculty f; student stu; TA t;
        p->setter("Anna");
        p = &f;
        p->print();
        p = &stu;
        p->print();
        faculty *fac = &t;
        fac->print();
        t.print("Bob");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In main, you are creating a pointer to a person and initializing that pointer to null: `person *p= NULL`

You then immediately dereference that null pointer: `p->setter("Anna");`

Also, judging by some of your wording, it sounds like you are using Visual Studio.  If that's the case, running the application through VS should jump straight to debug mode when you crash like this.  You can then look at the current state of the program and figure out why you crashed.

Comment: And this causes undefined behaviour ;)

Answer (score 2):

The following does not allocate an instance of a person:

```
    person *p= NULL;
```

It only created a pointer, and set the pointer to what ever NULL is currently defined as.

---

You probably meant to do something more like:

```
    person* p = new person;
```

Here, the new allocates space in the dynamic memory, and invokes the ctor of that class.

---

With p set to NULL (whatever NULL currently is),

```
p-><some method of p>
```

references a non-existent person instance at memory address 0. If that method tries to use any data attributes of the instance, on most common systems, that data access (near the very important addr 0) will trigger a fault.

Comment: Forgot to mention: missing in my code - always assert(<instance ptr>) when you new an object.   A nullptr might be returned (heap exhausted?), and suddenly you have same problem with less evidence of what is wrong.